# Get values of Object with Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an Object of Arrays with a key to identify each Array. I would like to make a `render` function, which can append the key's names to an unordered list in my HTML document, and append a new unordered list for each key, with a list of each value for that key.

**Example**

```
<ul>
  <li>Key1</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Value1</li>
      <li>Value2</li>
    </ul>
  <li>Key2</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Value1</li>
      <li>Value2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="expandable">
  <ul class="list">

  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let list = document.querySelector('.list')

let playslists = {
    'Pop' : [
        'Recurrent Pop Music',
        '1990s Pop - Greates',
        '2000s Pop - Greatest',
        '2010s Pop - Greatest'
    ],
    'Rock' : [
        'Recurrent Rock Music',
        '1990s Rock - Greatest',
        '2000s Rock - Greatest',
        '2010s Rock - Greatest'
    ]
}

function render(values) {    
    for(object in playslists) {
        // Fill list in HTML document.
    }
}

render()
```

**Question**

Can i get the keys and values of each object in the for-loop of my render function, to show a list on the webpage, with the keys as category and the values as the playlist names?

> ```
> Pop
> - Recurrent Pop Music
> - 1990s Pop - Greatest
> - 2000s Pop - Greatest
> - 2010s Pop - Greatest
> Rock
> - Recurrent Rock Music
> - 1990s Rock - Greatest
> - 2000s Rock - Greatest
> - 2010s Rock - Greatest
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution.

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.list'),
  p = {
    'Pop': [
      'Recurrent Pop Music',
      '1990s Pop - Greates',
      '2000s Pop - Greatest',
      '2010s Pop - Greatest'
    ],
    'Rock': [
      'Recurrent Rock Music',
      '1990s Rock - Greatest',
      '2000s Rock - Greatest',
      '2010s Rock - Greatest'
    ]
  };

function f(data) {
  Object.keys(p).forEach(function(v) {
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
        ul = document.createElement('ul');
    p[v].forEach(function(c) {
      var li2 = document.createElement('li');
      li2.textContent = c;
      ul.appendChild(li2);
    })
    li.textContent = v;
    li.appendChild(ul);
    list.appendChild(li);
  })
}

f(p);
```

```html
<div class="expandable">
  <ul class="list">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @gyre - I've picked this solution as the correct one instead of yours, because it maches what I am looking for more than yours. But thanks for the help anyways. :)

Comment: Thanks @KimJørgensen, I appreciate the follow-up. I would do it this way too if my HTML got to be more complex than bare tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the rendering of HTML using `Array` methods like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.list')

let playlists = {
  'Pop': [
    'Recurrent Pop Music',
    '1990s Pop - Greatest',
    '2000s Pop - Greatest',
    '2010s Pop - Greatest'
  ],
  'Rock': [
    'Recurrent Rock Music',
    '1990s Rock - Greatest',
    '2000s Rock - Greatest',
    '2010s Rock - Greatest'
  ]
}


function render() {
  list.innerHTML = '<li>' + Object.keys(playlists).map(function(k) {
    return k + '<ul><li>' + playlists[k].join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>'
  }).join('</li><li>') + '</li>'
}

render()
```

```html
<div class="expandable">
  <ul class="list">

  </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Here's how you would do it if you wanted to add classes and other attributes to the markup:

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.list')

let playlists = {
  'Pop': [
    'Recurrent Pop Music',
    '1990s Pop - Greatest',
    '2000s Pop - Greatest',
    '2010s Pop - Greatest'
  ],
  'Rock': [
    'Recurrent Rock Music',
    '1990s Rock - Greatest',
    '2000s Rock - Greatest',
    '2010s Rock - Greatest'
  ]
}

let OUTER_LI = '<li class="outer-list-item">'
let UL = '<ul class="inner-list">'
let INNER_LI = '<li class="inner-list-item">'

function render() {
  list.innerHTML = OUTER_LI + Object.keys(playlists).map(function(k) {
    return k + (UL + INNER_LI) + playlists[k].join('</li>' + INNER_LI) + '</li></ul>'
  }).join('</li>' + OUTER_LI) + '</li>'
}

render()
```

```css
.outer-list-item {
  color: red;
}

.inner-list {
  border: .1em solid green;
}

.inner-list-item {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="expandable">
  <ul class="list">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @gyre.

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: Though this is the correct answer, and I will accept is as such, would it be possible to write it in a way, so I am able to manipulate each <ul> and <li>?
To add classNames and such?

Comment: Of course! If you give me an example `class` attribute I can show you how it would be done via an edit.

Comment: I edited the post with an example of adding classes. Let me know what you think.

Comment: This is really good. If I wanted to make an eventListener on the top most <li> (Pop and Rock), how would I proceed to do it then?

Comment: It looks like you know how to use `querySelector`, so just select the elements *after* the HTML has been constructed (but still within `render`) and then call `addEventListener` on each element at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Just render the object name and then iterate its array, for example:

```
function render(values) {    
    for(object in playslists) {
        // Fill list in HTML document.
        let genre = document.createElement('div');
        genre.innerHTML = object;
        list.appendChild(genre)
        for(record in playslists[object]){
          let entry = document.createElement('li');
          entry.innerHTML = playslists[object][record];
          list.appendChild(entry)
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/me23dk3d/

Comment: the `values` argument is not used in your function. you are reassigning `values` in the second for in loop: `for(values in playslists[object])`